# How to separate an in between element to a new line if its content does not fit with CSS only?

Tags: css

The following is more like a general example.

```html
<div>
  <div>Short dynamic text.</div>
  <div id="in-between">Possible long dynamic text...</div>
  <div>Short dynamic text.</div>
</div>
```

Changing element order or types or adding helpers in between is beforehand is possible. All texts do not wrap. No fixed width or height must be given.

How to achieve something like this with CSS only and not by changing the DOM? So how to separate out some in between element to a new line if its content does not fit? Is it possible at all?

[image]

Some snippet to illustrate it in more detail and to test.

```css
.example {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  column-gap: 0.5rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.example .separate {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.example .long-b {
  order: 1; /* this should happen by some magic */
}

/* do not change below */

.container {
  border: 0.5rem solid black;
  background: blue;
}

.element {
 border: 0.5rem solid yellow;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 color: white;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.short-a:before {
  content: "only three words";
}

.short-b:before {
 content: "flag";
}

.short-c:before {
  content: "i love stackoverflow";
}

.short-d:before {
 content: "attribute";
}

.long-a:before {
  content: "i am not that long";
}

.long-b:before {
  content: "i am very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long";
}
```

```html
<div class="container example">
  <div class="element short-a"></div>
  <div class="element separate long-a"></div>
  <div class="element short-b"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="container example">
  <div class="element short-c"></div>
  <div class="element separate long-b"></div>
  <div class="element short-d"></div>
</div>
```

The current answer is helpful and acceptable. Nevertheless is there (or will there be) some other approach not utilizing float?

Comment: You could use `display: grid` and media queries

Comment: @KārlisKazāks your comment is irrelevant. `@media` queries have nothing to do with content length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

float is the only solution here BUT you have to adjust the HTML structure (I know it's against your requirement but the below may give you some ideas)

```css
.box {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
  /* to debug */
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
  /**/
}
.box > div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box > :first-child {
  float: left;
}
.box > :nth-child(2) {
  float: right;
}

#in-between {
  display: inline-block;
  
  /* remove the below if you want text wrap instead of ellpsis*/
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>Short dynamic text.</div>
  <div>Short dynamic text.</div>
  <div id="in-between">Possible long dynamic text Possible long text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is ok to change the structure in general beforehand. I meant not to change it afterwards e.g. by some JS to separate the element. Your approach seems suitable for me! I also played around with float but only on one side. Both sides do the trick. Thx!